# How to send something to an OutputStream

Tags: java, process, io, processbuilder

How can is send something to an OutputStream?

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "something.jar");
Process p = pb.start();

OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();

//Already tried this:
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes());
in.transferTo(out); //But this says: This method is undefined for the type: InputStream
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap it with DataOutputStream class, then you can use the writeUTF() method to write string objects.

Answer (score -1):

Already found out:
For anyone who is looking

```html
out.write("say hello".getBytes());
```

Comment: If you're going to be writing text to your output stream, it's best to wrap it in an `OutputStreamWriter` so that you don't have to keep calling `getBytes`.